# ASP.NET MVC: Is it a good practice to check existence of a Linq Object in database by exception handling?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC application, when I'm going to fetch an item, I usually check its existence by using `Any()` then I will fetch that item by `.Single()`.
However it comes to my mind to decrease number of database queries, and I tried to use this structure:

```
item myItem = null;

try
{
    myItem = (from item in dbContext.items
              where item.id == itemID
              select item).Single();
}
catch (Exception e)
{

    // i understand item is not exist in db
}

// if item is available  
if (myItem ==null){
    //item was not in db
}else{
    //item is present id db
}
```

It only fetch database once, and if item does not exist it will throw exception so I do not need to check for `Any()` results any more.
Is this improve the efficiency of my application or it will cause some degradation due to exception handling?

Comment: Why don't you use `SingleOrDefault()`. Then you won't  need the exception handling for that situation and the remainder of the code can stay intact.

Comment: without forgetting SingleOrDefault must be used on returned single row guarantee cases. if dbContext.items retured more then one result it throw an exception. it would be use FirstOrDefault and FirstOrDefault is working faster then SingleOrDefault

Comment: One important consideration also is how expensive throwing exceptions is. Only throw exceptions in, er, exceptional circumstances!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. Why don't you use `SingleOrDefault()`. Then you won't  need the exception handling for that situation and the remainder of the code can stay intact.

Answer (score 0):

If you think there will be a value or a possible null, then use `SingleOrDefault`:

```
myItem = (from item in dbContext.items
              where item.id == itemID
              select item).SingleOrDefault();
```

Then check it:

```
// if item is available  
if (myItem ==null){
    //item was not in db
}else{
    //item is present id db
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other answers it is better to use .SingleOrDefault() and if you are using C# 6 you can use [null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595(v=vs.140).aspx) to simplify the expression.

```
myItem = (from item in dbContext.items
          where item.id == itemID
          select item).SingleOrDefault();
var somePropertyValue = myItem?.SomeProperty;
```

myItem?.SomeProperty will return value of the property or null if myItem is null.